# Dynamic Factor Model Estimation

Tags: python, matlab, statistics, modeling

I'm looking for a Python or Matlab based package which can estimate parameters for the following model:

[image: Model]

In the original paper they refer to [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzOpR8T359fhQi1GMkdLd0RLckE/view?resourcekey=0-AaHu7KfomK0CHCYFr3KpfQ) code by Koop. The problem I have is that this program as well the standard packages from Python's statsmodel estimate a DFM of the form:

[image: Standard model]

The difference to the model in the paper is that if we have two factors, then A_1 is two-dimensional, but in the model I want to estimate, we only want to estimate a_11 and assume a_12 = 0. Is there a package which can estimate such models?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this in Statsmodels, although there are trade-offs to each approach:

(1) If you are okay with 1 lag for the error terms (i.e. if it is okay to have e(i,t) = \phi(i,1) e(i,t-1) + u(i,t), from your linked "Model" equations), then you can use the `DynamicFactorMQ` class. For two factors that evolve independently, you can use the following:

```
mod = sm.tsa.DynamicFactorMQ(y, factors=['f1', 'f2'],
                             factor_orders={'f1':1, 'f2':1},
                             idiosyncratic_ar1=True)
res = mod.fit()
```

See [here](https://www.chadfulton.com/topics/statespace_large_dynamic_factor_models.html#model-specification) for more details on how the `factors` and `factor_orders` arguments work. Basically, by specifying `factor_orders={'f1':1, 'f2':1}` instead of `factor_orders={('f1', 'f2'):1}` (which is the default if you don't specify anything), the factors evolve separately (which is the same as having diagonal A matrices).

(2) Otherwise, if you do not have too many left-hand-side variables, you could use the `DynamicFactor` class with fixed parameters:

```
mod = sm.tsa.DynamicFactor(std, factor_order=1, k_factors=2,
                           error_order=1,
                           enforce_stationarity=False)
with mod.fix_params({'L1.f2.f1': 0, 'L1.f1.f2': 0}):
    res = mod.fit()
```

In this case, when you do `mod.fix_params({'L1.f2.f1': 0, 'L1.f1.f2': 0})`, you are specifying that a_12 = a_21 = 0. See [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_fixed_params.html) for some more details about using `fix_params`.

But in general, the `DynamicFactorMQ` class from option (1) above is more robust, and is likely the better option.

Comment: that worked perfectly. the only issue is that while i can estimate the model, the parameters seem far off from the parameters im trying to replicate. The reason is that the other algorithm uses a Bayesian approach with a Gibbs Sampling Algorithm. I probably need to be able to amend the Matlab code to achieve that